# Quotient of indicatorfunction and probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am having trouble to proof following statement.

If $A_1,A_2,..$ are pairwise independent and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(A_n)=\infty$ then as $n\rightarrow \infty$

$\frac{\sum_{m=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{A_m}}{\sum_{m=1}^n \mathbb{P}(A_m) } \rightarrow 1$   almost surely.

We already showed that this expression converges in probability to 1. Now i was told to choose a subsequence and show that this subsequences converges almost surely to 1.

Comment: I do not see how to use the hint. Showing the almost sure convergence of a subsequence does not seem simpler than the original problem. We can use Chebyschev's inequality and we can conclude from the Borel-Cantelli lemma if the series $\sum c_n^{-1}$ converges where $c_n=\sum_{i=1}^nP(A_i)$.